# Cordova watchPosition speed

Tags: cordova, gps

I've developped an app who uses watchposition to get speed.

But when I'm using my application in my car, the speed never come back to 0.

```
onDeviceReady: function() {
    initPushwoosh();
    id = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(successCallback, errorCallback, {enableHighAccuracy:true, maximumAge:0, timeout:250});
```

Is there any solution ?

Thank you

Comment: Are the permissions correctly applied? Does the GPS turn on when the app is launched?

Comment: Yes it works. I have the current speed but when my car is stopped, the speed is like 12, 5... But never comeback to 0 km

Answer (score 1):

I check the speed with this source code :

```
  var speed_convert = position.coords.speed || null;
      if(isNaN(parseFloat(speed_convert)) || speed_convert <= 0 || speed_convert == null)
        speed_convert = 0;
      else {
        speed_convert = speed_convert * 3.6;
        speed_convert = Math.round(speed_convert);
      }
```

But the speed never come back to 0

Comment: And I called this function from my onDeviceReady